# How can I extend this circuit to use it in our real life?

Tags: charger, mobile

I am planning to design a wireless mobile charger circuit next week. For that purpose, I have selected the circuit which is shown below and is collected from the post: **[wireless mobile battery charger](http://www.electronicshub.org/wireless-mobile-battery-charger-circuit/)**.

[image]

I am also planning to add some extra features to that circuit. So, can anybody give any ideas and suggestions to extend the circuit for real-world applications. Additionally, which values are to be given to those capacitors and resistors to make it function in real life.

Comment: That schematic and the article it came from are complete rubbish. Keep looking.

Comment: It's not the poster's fault that the site he found is rubbish. Question is OK - downvote not a great idea.

Comment: Lack of knowledge doesn't deserve a downvote. Coming here to check out the circuit is sensible.

Comment: [The most recent article on that site](http://www.electronicshub.org/different-types-of-semiconductors/) also claims that resistors, capacitors, fuses, and inductors are semiconductor components. Um…

Comment: Actually, based on what I see in some of the other posts, I bet they're "building" all these circuits in a simulator (there's videos of it on some posts), and this circuit "works" due to bugs in the simulator.

Answer (score 9):

The circuit you have shown WILL NOT WORK: -

[image]

It shows a transmitter and receiver of power (top and bottom). The transmitter of power has some kind of rectifier THAT WON'T WORK - both diodes are facing the same way - it needs to be a bridge rectifier. Then it shows an oscillator - THIS WON'T WORK - there is no active device to control the oscillation and no connection to ground for the current in the coil to be developed.